# ¿Qué significa “de” en "el descastado de su hijo"?

Tags: preposiciones

> Le pregunté quién le había dado esa paliza. Mientras se rascaba el
>   barro del pantalón, me contestó furioso que había sido **el descastado
>   de su hijo**.

Tengo la duda que *el descastado* se refiere a *su hijo*, por qué dice “**de** su hijo” que me parece *"de alguien de su hijo"*.

Y, si dice en otra manera, ¿puedo decir “...*había sido de su hijo, el cual / lo que era un descastado*”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es una buena pregunta. En español, existe esa estructura, que es un poco extraña.

Aquí, la palabra "de" no es posesivo, sino solamente un enlace.

"El descastado de su hijo" = " su hijo, **que es muy** descastado"

Es una estructura un poco extraña. Descastado es **el hijo**, no "alguien del hijo".

En general, a veces se usan estructuras como esta; habitualmente con sentido peyorativo.

```
El idiota de su padre = Su padre, que es un idiota.
La buenaza de su amiga = Su amiga, que es una buenaza.
```

Esta estructura significa lo mismo que

```
Su hijo, que está hecho un descastado.
```

Comment: Hay que notar también el potencial de esta estructura para los dobles sentidos: *la perra de tu novia* = "la perra que pertenece a tu novia" o "tu novia, que es una perra".

Answer (score 3):

El diccionario de la RAE recoge este uso de [la preposición *de*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BtFYznp):

> 15. prep. U. para reforzar un calificativo. *El bueno de Pedro. El pícaro del mozo. La taimada de la patrona.*

Al contrario que en otras acepciones en las que sí se indica que se usa para expresar pertenencia, aquí simplemente se usa para reforzar un calificativo, ayudando a unirlo con el calificado. Así, *el descastado de su hijo* equivale a *su descastado hijo*.

Por tanto, otras formas de decir la frase serían:

> Me contestó furioso que había sido su descastado hijo.
>   Me contestó furioso que había sido su hijo, que era un descastado.

Si te resulta más fácil verlo como una relación de posesión o pertenencia, se podría decir que esta relación sería entre el hijo y el grupo de las personas descastadas: el grupo de los descastados contiene al hijo (este pertenece al grupo).

Curiosamente, la definición que da el *Diccionario de Autoridades* (1732) nos da una pista para distinguir este uso de la preposición (escritura adaptada):

> Se usa familiarmente y con gran frecuencia interpuesto entre dos nombres para mayor viveza de la expresión, y aunque suena como genitivo de posesión no lo es, porque los dos nombres están concertados en un mismo caso.

Es decir, que si dices "la casa de mi padre", los casos (género y número) son independientes para *casa* y para *padre*: podrías decir "las casas de mi padre" o "la casa de mi madre" o "la casa de mis padres" y las expresiones resultantes seguirían siendo gramaticalmente válidas. Pero si cambias *el descastado de su hijo* por *la descastada de su hija* fíjate que tienes que cambiar el género en ambos casos obligatoriamente, y también el número: *las descastadas de sus hijas*. Esto indica sin lugar a dudas que *descastado* no es más que un adjetivo de *hijo*.

Comment: Dime por favor el solícito fue un error? Es solo una pregunta porque no sé porque desapareció. :)